# Damping and angular frequency of the system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, differential-equations

[image]Hello. I didn't have enough exercises from differential equations and I'm a bit lost on what should I do. I have an equation of motion of this system and I have to find the natural angular frequency ω0 and the damping ratio δ.

Assumptions:

1. F1 = F2 = F + f(t)
2. disk $m_{sb}$ doesn't perform any oscillation -> model has a single degree of freedom: deflection φ. Due to this assumption cos φ ≅ 1.

​

I have tried to use the angular momentum theory so I used the equation:

sum[moments of forces] = moments of inertia of the system around A * angular acceleration φ.

I don't know if that's a correct way so I will be grateful for any tips or the very beginning of the calculations.

Comment: Sum of the torques about A is correct, to obtain the angular frequency and the damping you don’t need to take care about the external forces. Additional inertia force from the mass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the free body diagram

[image]

Take the sum of the torques about point A